# MailGun trying to post JSON object

Tags: c#, json, mailgun

```
public async Task Main()
{
    var serviceCo = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigServices(serviceCo);
    var services = serviceCo.BuildServiceProvider();
    var httpClientFactory = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("api:MyApiKey"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64String);
    var DomainId = "MyDomain";

    JArray json = JArray.Parse("[{'address': 'alice@example.com','createdat': ''},{'address': 'bob@example.com','createdat': ''}]");

    var postData = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var request = await client.PostAsync("https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/" + DomainId + "/complaints", postData);

    var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(response);

}
```

I'm trying to post list of "complaints" to mailgun API. https://documentation.mailgun.com/docs/mailgun/api-reference/openapi-final/tag/Complaints/#tag/Complaints/operation/api.(*ComplaintController).InsertJSON-fm-36

I get a response back with:

> "StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'".

Also a message:

> {"message":"Missing mandatory parameter: address"}\n.

I'm not sure exactly whats wrong. I'm guessing it's my JSON.

Comment: Please post the result of the call to `json.ToString()`. Yes, I know it's two lines above. I am just curious about something.

Comment: [
  {
    "address": "alice@example.com",
    "createdat": ""
  },
  {
    "address": "bob@example.com",
    "createdat": ""
  }
]

Comment: According to the documentation, `createdat` should be an `object`. Try changing your JSON to `"createdat": {}`, see if that makes it work. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just tried it but still same thing. Respense is {"message":"Missing mandatory parameter: address"}.   I have managed to add a single object by adding a parameter to url /complaints?address=test3 but this only adds a single complain and ignores the Json I sent.

Comment: What if you remove the open `[` and close `]` brackets from the string? Something is tripping their parser. Maybe this does it. Just send `{ "address": "alice@example.com", "createdat": {} }, { "address": "bob@example.com", "createdat": {} }`.

Comment: Still same issue if I remove [  ]

Comment: seems the string you do JArray.Parse is using ' not " for string, not sure whether it matters.

Comment: also, why you use JArray.Parse, then POST json.ToString() ? the string you parsed, supposed to be the json you want to POST,I think

Comment: Yeah maybe that's not needed. I tried var postData = new StringContent("[{'address': 'alice@example.com','createdat': {}},{'address': 'bob@example.com','createdat': {}}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); but that had same result "message":"Missing mandatory parameter: address"

Comment: use ", not '. escape " in the string.

Comment: I tried it like this. Since just having " doesn't wotk. var postData = new StringContent("[{\"address\": \"alice@example.com\",\"createdat\": {}},{\"address\": \"bob@example.com\",\"createdat\": {}}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Comment: createdat - incorrect. must be 'created_at' :{}

Comment: try this: JArray json = JArray.Parse("[{\"address\": \"alice@example.com\",\"created_at\": {}},{\"address\": \"bob@example.com\",\"created_at\": {}}]");

Comment: @JDraz Did you figure this out? I would love to know the solution. If not, I would suggest reaching out to Mailgun directly.